# How can I know if threads are running in the same process?

Tags: android, multithreading, process

I am trying to understand the difference between a thread and a process.
I have 3 examples in mind:

1- if a thread is launched from the main Activity and do some work
2- When a thread is launched from the main Activity and keep running indefinitely like for example a server
3- when a the UI Threads calls a thread-> calls another thread

How can I know if threads are running in the same process?
The documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 1):

When Android starts an application, it runs inside a Linux a process with one thread. The UI Thread. All your threads belong to the same process.